# ptrace with request PTRACE_POKETEXT fails

Tags: linux, ptrace

i'm trying to inject code in a traced process...i'm able to read correctly registers (`PTRACE_GETREGS`) and also `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT` works...i've verified with GDB. However if i call `ptrace` with `PTRACE_POKETEXT` request it returns `0` but reading again at the same address i don't find the expected bytes:

```
void print_word(long res) {
    char *datap = (char *)&res;

    if (res == -1)
        //check errno for errors
    else
        printf("%02X %02X %02X %02X\n", datap[0], datap[1], datap[2], datap[3]);
}

....

long res, data = 0xAABBCCDD;

res = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, pid, (void *)regs.eip, NULL);
print_word(res);
res = ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, pid, (void *)regs.eip, (void *)&data);
if (res != 0)
    //error
res = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, pid, (void *)regs.eip, NULL);
print_word(res);
```

The first `print_word` prints exactly the four bytes displayed by GDB. The second `print_word` instead prints strange bytes and not `0xAABBCCDD`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those strange bytes that you get from the second `ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, ...)` should match the address of `data` - compare them with the value of `&data`.

Although the manual page of `ptrace(2)` shows the `data` argument as `void *`, for the `PTRACE_POKETEXT` request `data` holds the request value. Using the *address-of* operator you actually poke the address of the value instead of the value itself. The correct invocation is as follows:

```c
res = ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, pid, (void *)regs.eip, (void *)data); // w/o &
if (res != 0)
    //error
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. My fault! The fourth param must be a pointer to support all the other requests, but do you know the reason why that param, with `PTRACE_POKETEXT`, is no treated as a pointer?

Comment: `ptrace` is a variadic function, i.e. different requests take different arguments. I believe this particular request takes the data directly (and not a pointer to it) in order to save one userspace- to kernel-space copy operation.